# There are no commands defined in the "notifications" namespace

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to run `php artisan notifications:table` , but I receive the following error :
There are no commands defined in the "notifications" namespace.

I'm on laravel version 5.2.36

Comment: Notifications has been implemented on Laravel 5.5

Comment: Notifications we not introduced into Laravel until version **5.3**. This is why you're getting the error.